# flask wtforms , multiple tags in input Filed from QuerySelectField from DB

Tags: python, flask, input, tags, flask-wtforms

i have a simple form created with flask wtforms, in this form a have an input field that must contains a multiple tags from tables tags in my databases, this tables is not linked to any other table in my database.
this is the model:

```
class Tag(db.Model):
__tablename__ = 'tags'
id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
tag_name = db.Column(db.String(50))
tag_description = db.Column(db.String(100))
tag_color = db.Column(db.String(10))
```

forms.py :

```
def get_tags_name():
      return Tag.query

tags = QuerySelectField('TAGS :', query_factory =  get_tags_name, get_label = "tag_name",allow_blank = True, render_kw={"multiple": "multiple"})
```

this input give me a multichoses selectfieled, i need to have a multiple tags input.
example in image:

[image]

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use JqueryUI TokenFieled, this is the implementation.

https://sliptree.github.io/bootstrap-tokenfield/